# Creating a variable if a form input field contains data using PHP

Tags: php, forms

I am working on a project for one of my professors and have added a way to dynamically add input fields as shown here:

[image]

Before creating this form I had 6 sets of input fields and was posting them using the following code in PHP:

```
$author1 = $_POST['author1_name'];
$author1uni = $_POST['author1_university'];
$author2 = $_POST['author2_name'];
$author2uni = $_POST['author2_university'];
$author3 = $_POST['author3_name'];
$author3uni = $_POST['author3_university'];
$author4 = $_POST['author4_name'];
$author4uni = $_POST['author4_university'];
$author5 = $_POST['author5_name'];
$author5uni = $_POST['author5_university'];
$author6 = $_POST['author6_name'];
$author6uni = $_POST['author6_university'];
```

I'd like to set these variables if they exists by doing something like :

```
$num = 1;
if (!empty($_POST['author' . $num]){
$author . $num = $_POST['author' . $num];
$num++;
}
```

in order to post the variables. I read that this is called variable variables and that it was bad practice. What would be the best method? I'm new to programming so I apologize if this question is dumb or not right for Stack Overflow but I've spent hours on this only to find out it was bad practice and don't want to make the same mistake twice. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Why not use arrays instead?

Comment: use array `<input type="text" name="author_name[]">  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use arrays as names for input in your view like this

```
name="author_name[]"
name="author_university[]"
```

in php

```
foreach($_POST['author_name'] as $key => $val) {
      echo $val."====>".$_POST["author_university"][$key];
     //will echo corresponding author name and university.
}
```

For your reference, use `isset()` but works fine without that as well.

Comment: I need to post these to variables not print them out. What is this method called that you have showed me here? I am not fully understanding it

Comment: i have just echoed the values there... you can capture in an array and use it for further use...

Comment: What do you mean by capture in an array? Does this foreach loop do that?

Comment: what is your database structure??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96280/discussion-between-taylor-clark-and-niranjan-n-raju).

Answer (score 0):

you can have like below code multiple times:

```
<input name="author[]" type="text"/>
<input name="uni[]" type="text"  />
```

and after posting

```
$_POST['author'];
$_POST['uni'];
```

this will contain  all fields value, loop through it like this:

```
foreach($_POST['author'] as $key => $val) {
    echo $val." and ".$_POST["uni"][$key];
}
```